# How to validate a form field against a json file using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, forms, validation

I have a form that I only want people to be able to submit if it is from a list of values that are in a json file.  The Json file would be {"1","2","3",......}.  I have been trying to search all over but I a m unable to find something that works like that.  I feel like this is relatively simple but since I am new to jquery/JS its a bit tricky to build from scratch.

If anyone has a good direction to point me that would be super helpful or some handy good -- even better!

Right now I am trying to hack together some code from below but it doesn't seem to want to do the trick.

```
<script>
  $.getJSON("countries.json", function(json) {
    $('#signup').on('submit', function(evt) {
        var user = $('#user').val(), error;
        if (!user)
            error = 'no username entered';
        else if (json.usernames.indexOf(user) != -1)
            error = 'username already taken';
    if (error) { evt.preventDefault(); alert(error); }
    });
});
  </script>


<form id='signup'>
    <label>Enter value here</label>
    <input type='text' id='user' />
    <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

Thanks!  I was also trying to use bootstraps typeahead but it decided to break down with my bootstrap 3.0 css file :|

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider  using JQuery validation and adding a custom validator, where the validator would perform your Id/usrname check and if successful allow the form to submit, or not otherwise.

In the example below, the custom validation - provided by the "usersExistsCheck" function -  covers off your Id check, and the required validation ensures a value is entered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.validator.addMethod("userExistsCheck", 
                         function(value, element) {
                            // Your test on ids/username in here
                        }, 
                         "Can not submit as the user already exists."
  );

  $("#signup").validate({   
      rules: {
          user: { //where user is the id of the user input box.
              required: true,
              userExistsCheck: true
          }

      },
      messages: {
         user: {
               required: "* Required"
           }
       }    
   });
```

})

Adapted from this blog post:
http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/starting-with-jquery-how-to-write.html

Comment: You may want to quote the actual text of the blog that describes the solution; in case the blog changes it's url or gets deleted, to mantain the consistency of the answer.

Comment: @brumScouse -- thanks -- I have re worked to include what I think is the correct way to get the validation and attached it below -- it isn't quite working as expected in firefox right now though.  Thanks.